# Recommendations for a two port KVM switch

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse

Due to developers needing access to one Mac and one PC we need to install KVM switches so both computers can share a keyboard, monitor and mouse.

There are only a few requirements:

- DVI (but VGA is okay)
- USB mouse
- USB keyboard
- No mod/extra key funniness

Regarding the last point, special keys (like Eject on the Mac keyboards) should work as expected. I've read that some KVMs interfere with or have side effects with some special keys and I'd like to avoid that.

We don't need to be able to share more than two computers but supporting more isn't a deal breaker. Having a low profile and/or being mountable is a bonus. Will consider all price points.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 3):

I cant recommend a specific brand, but if you can get one that doesnt require drivers to work its more convenient.

Comment: +1 for not requiring drivers.  Might I also suggest a switch that allows you to quickly switch between computers via hot keys on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I use and am happy with [IOGear MiniView Micro DVI-D KVM with Audio and cables (GCS932U)](http://www.iogear.com/product/GCS932U/)

Comment: +1 I also have had great experiences with IOGear KVMs

Answer (score 0):

We use a few **[ATEN KVM Switches](http://www.aten.com/products/product_alternative.php)**, I can't complain.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a [Belkin SOHO](http://catalog.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=404605#) right now, it works great.  One thing I love about it is that you can switch the audio separately from the video.  I have the two port version, it's a little on the pricy side ($219)

Comment: Whoa, that is pricey. Switching video and audio independently looks like a very enticing feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have an IOGear Miniview GCS1764 - 4 port DVI KVM that works great.  It supports 1920 x 1080 resolution perfectly as well as a USB keyboard and mouse.  It switches from buttons on the device itself rather than a hotkey and I have had no problems switching between a Mac mini and a PC.  The audio switching works well, though I don't use the USB device switching.

A few caveats

- I have to reset the KVM (pull power) once every few months or so.
- I don't know if it supports special keys like the Eject key.
- It was expensive for a small KVM - in the $200 range.